# JOIN 2 tables without records replication

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have 2 tables:

1:

```
id | name
1  | test
2  | test1
```

2.

```
id | related_id | additional
1  | 1          | 1         
2  | 1          | 2
```

id in 1 table relates with related_id in 2

How to JOIN 1 table with 2 without replication records, so the result will be only 1 row from second table (related_id and additional can be any)

```
id | name | related_id | additional
1  | test | 1          | 1
2  | test1| NULL       | NULL
```

**Update**
IF I try to group after INNER/LEFT JOIN, the result is

```
id | name | related_id | additional
1  | test | 1          | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the result with the primary key

```
select * 
from table1 left join table2
on table1.id = table2.related_id
group by table1.id
```

Comment: I did a quick example (name and additional not exactly with the same data), and with the left join I got the desired result, two rows for me

Comment: With the exact data in table1 and table2, the LEFT JOIN obtains two rows exactly as your expected result, the difference with an INNER JOIN is precisely that second row filled with NULLs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(id),
            related_id
        FROM table2
    ) as t2
ON t1.id = t2.related_id
```

Comment: Beware of the subquery with the max(id),related_id because it doesn't get a correct result, if you have more than one row with the same (id) the value of related_id won't correspond to the id extracted; you need to do another additional subquery over the max(id) obtained alone